# Do some Action with Ajax Method Success

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have Jquery Ajax method to call MVC controller action. With the return value in this method i want do some action with if condition. This method call in save button click. If return true i wanna do return save action, if return false i wanna show validations.

This is my Ajax method:

```
   $(function () {
    $('#saveRefund').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var userName = $('#userName').val();
        var password = $('#Password').val();

        var sucess = setRefundformValidation()
        if (sucess) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Service/Utility/IsLoginSucess',
                data: { userName: userName, password: password },
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    if (data == 0) {
                        $('#loginVal_').show();
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#loginVal_').hide();
                        return true;
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        else
        { return false; }

    });
});
```

consider this function 
if (data == 0) show validation,

if (data != 0) return form action

if return true this is not redirect to SAVE action in controller

Please help this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because ajax is asynchronous, your return true/return false will not work on the ajax call and will return false every time.

Asyncronous means it will not wait for the success result, and will pass straight through it processing the code directly after the entire ajax call, this would mean a default value of return false would be returned every time. By the time your success returns true, the function has already returned false preventing further action.

Instead of return true, you should call a function for what you want to do if true, and instead of return false, you should again call a function to handle what you want if false.